# Any way to Externalize microprofile-config.properties file in Helidon MP

Tags: java, helidon, eclipse-microprofile-config

I am new to Helidon MP and would like to know if there is a way to externalize Helidon MP Properties file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to read up on [MicroProfile Config's notion of `ConfigSource`s](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/configsources.asciidoc#configsources).  The [guide to Helidon MP configuration](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/config/01_introduction) might be of use as well.